# PostgreSQL error when trying to connect in python : invalid dsn: invalid connection option "username"

Tags: python, mysql, database, postgresql, psycopg2

So I have got this task:
You have two abstract reports made available to you on a PostgreSQL server located at: postgres://candidate.company.org/company

username = candidate password = abc

So I used this code to try connect to the database:

```
import psycopg2 as db
conn = db.connect(host='postgres://candidate.suade.org/company', database='randomname', user='candidate', password='abc', port='5432')
```

But then i receiver error message:

```
ProgrammingError: invalid dsn: invalid connection option "username"
```

As the username give is correct Can anyone help?

Comment: The `connect` uses *dbname* as argument per [docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/module.html).

Comment: Please remove invalid tag "mysql". Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You are using the wrong parameters. In Postgres you have to use something like this:

```
conn = pg.DB(host="localhost", user="USERNAME", passwd="PASSWORD", dbname="DBNAME")
```

That should fix it.

Comment: but dont i have to access postgresql with the psycopg2 on python so with that as i did as i rightly first imported psycopg2 as  bd then connected it with conn = db.connect(host="localhost", username="USERNAME", passwd="PASSWORD", dbname="DBNAME")?? or where am i getting it wring here as the error comes ProgrammingError: invalid dsn: invalid connection option "username"

Comment: @robertjames it should be `user=`, not `username=`.

Comment: It should be password and not passwd.

Answer (score 1):

Please try with below solution

```
import psycopg2 as db
conn = db.connect(host='localhost', dbname='randomname', user='candidate', password='abc')
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `psycopg2`  library to connect the Postgres DB , then the connection string should be as mentioned below .

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(host="localhost",**user = "postgres"**,password = "postgres",database = "postgres") ;
```

It should be user not username .